# Perl converting base64 back to binary

Tags: string, perl, base64, decoding

I have a binary string of the form

```
"000000110111010100110110001010001010110111010110010001111111101010000001"  # for example
```

to encode to base 64, i use pack and encode_base64

```
my $base64 = encode_base64 pack 'B*', $binaryString;
```

Which I would then get.

```
A3U2KK3WR/qB
```

I would like to revert back to the original binary form of the string, I tried

```
my $binString = decode_base64 $base64;
```

but that returns

```
u6(��G��
```

How can i revert back the original binary string?

Comment: Looks like your problem needs some unpacking.

Comment: [Live demo](http://ideone.com/MyXIg5) of the unpacked result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inverse of

```
my $base64 = encode_base64(pack('B*', $binary));
```

is

```
my $binary = unpack('B*', decode_base64($base64));
```

Comment: Note: I assume length($binary) is always evenly divisible by 8. If its not, there isn't enough information in `$base64` to recreate the original string.

Comment: thank you, works perfectly, feeling pretty dump that i forgot to unpack